# Center an Icon inside a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I've seen multiple posts about centering an Icon inside a button but I need to center an Icon inside a TextView, the icons is set on the left with `android:drawableLeft`. Also I can't add extra layouts or views.

Comment: Assuming that you also have text in the `TextView`, either use emoji or `ImageSpan`.

Comment: set icon as a background to the `TextView` but in this way your text will be overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using drawableleft, use "drawableTop". This will put the icon on the center and the text below. You can modify the position of your text using "gravity".

If you're using Android Studio, you can search on the search bar of your layout the word "drawabletop" and that will appear.